# Fragment Layout not changing in OnConfiguration Change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I want to change my Fragment layout while changing the rotation of my Phone.But somehow the recent view is not coming.

The parent view is removed but the new View is not loaded.Its showing a white screen.This is my onConfig method from Fragment class.

```
   @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);




    System.out.println("On COnfiguration change has been called:--");
    LayoutInflater mCurrentinflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup mCurrentContainer = mContainer;
    View currentView = mCurrentinflater.inflate(R.layout.rashi_grid, mContainer,false);

    StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.removeAllViews();

    ((ViewGroup) mCurrentContainer.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    View rootView = mCurrentinflater.inflate(R.layout.rashi_grid, mCurrentContainer, false);

    mCurrentContainer.addView(rootView);
    gridView.addView(View.inflate(currentView.getContext(), R.layout.rashi_grid, mCurrentContainer));

}
```

Please help..I have two layout.the rashi_grid.xml file is located in res\layout folder and another one is located in res\layout-land folder.Please help

**EDIT**

This is my HomeActivity.class

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity_home);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }





}



@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("booleanValue")) {
        boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("booleanValue");
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}



@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    outState.putBoolean("booleanValue", true);
}



/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item

        displayView(position);
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    System.out.println("Item Id:-"+item.getTitle());
   if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
 private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

  Fragment fragment = null;


    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new AFragment();
        break;

    case 1:
        fragment = new BFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null ) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        //fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

  @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls

    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


  }



}
```

This is my BFragment

```
@Override
// Called when the fragment is created.
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    mContainer = container;

    // Inflation of the fragment layout.
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rashi_grid, container, false);    

    BImageAdapter adapter = new BImageAdapter(getActivity());


    StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    //GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent product = new Intent(getActivity(),productActivity.class);
            product.putExtra("productname", position);
            startActivity(product);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

This is my BimageAdapter

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder vh;

    if (v == null)
    {
    vh = new ViewHolder();
    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
    vh.productname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.productname);
    vh.productprice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    vh.productpricedetails = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.product_pricedetails);
    vh.imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    v.setTag(vh); 
    }
    else 
    { 
    vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();  
    }       

    vh.productpricedetails.setText(productprice[position]);
    vh.productname.setText(productName[position]);
    vh.imageView.setImageResource(ImageId[position]);
    vh.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);






    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the layout of the fragment, you should rather not use `onConfigurationChanged`. Let the activity and the fragments be destroyed and recreated and do the inflation of the layout in activitie's `onCreate`.

Better still, you can just define your layouts for landscape and portrait in the proper folders (`layout-land` and `layout-port`) with the same file name. This way it will pick up the correct layout automatically without you doing any code (as long as the activity and fragments are recreated).

Comment: in my activity class if i override onConfig method then the layout is not changing..its getting the same layout,only the width is expanding.But i have different views for landscape and potrait

Comment: You use `onConfigurationChanged` if you DON"T want to restart your activity. Is that what you want? You only do that if you have a good reason.

Comment: Yes i dont want to restart my activity..just i want to change the layout from potrait to landscape..but somehow its not happening

Comment: What I wanted to say is that the easiest way to change your layout is to restart your activity, define layouts in proper folders and let it work automatically.

Comment: then if i restart my activity the from the activity class onConfig changes method should be removed or from the fragment class it should be removed ?

Comment: i have changed my app accoridng to your suggestion.Now from landscape -> potrait the layout is perfect...but from potrait -> landscape its giving error.. !!!

Comment: some array index out of bound error.. i am using staggeredgrid view..so the first row is not coming while changing the layout from potrait -> landscape... so its giving array index out of bound

Comment: Please help.. @Szymon

Answer (score 0):

1. When we Change orientation fragments are recreated. So when we want not to call onCreate on orientation change we override method(onConfiguration)
   2.if you don't want the activity restart when orientation changed, 
   Declare given Tag in Menifest

//Writing this tag in menifest is necessary so the app handle the handle the config change instead ofandroid.

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden" 
or 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

1. To change layout in configuration change replace below given code.
   In your code do one thing check the orientation changes in OnConfigurationChanged.

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
   {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

   ```
       // Checks the orientation of the screen
   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
   {
       setContentView(R.layout.listslandscape);
   } 
   else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
   {
       setContentView(R.layout.listsportrait);
   }
   ```

   }

to know more you can go to android developer site. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html